Correct way to handle non-blocking image processing
I have an JavaScript extension that in short: upon user action, converts an image into a dataURI (and then does some processing)
Problem:
My issue is that using callbacks becomes unpleasant to deal with if more processing is required, for example, scaling, modifying, etc, where I use similar functions (load into a canvas, return result via callback) as they become nested and so on. It'd be better to keep things inline.
Question:
I'd like to use await image.decode(), instead of image.onload => () {}, but I'm afraid if I use await, it'll block the rest of the page, waiting for it to load.
I've read up on many an article and SO question, and I thought I understood asynchronous calls, but I'd just like to be certain.
Or should I even be using Promises?
Here's what I've used so far -
function getImageDataURL(imageSource, callback){
  let image = new Image();
  let cans = document.createElement('canvas');
  
  image.onload = function() {
    // processing 
    cans.width = this.naturalWidth;
    cans.height = this.naturalHeight;
    cans.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0,0);
    let q = 1
    while (cans.toDataURL("image/webp", q).length > 7500 && q != 0) {
      q -= 0.05; // Decreased quality increment size
    }
    callback(cans.toDataURL("image/webp", q));
    cans.remove(); // Remove Element once complete
  }
  image.src = imageSource;
}

And I understand when the image load starts, it releases control of the execution to the rest of the page.
Which is good, as the user experience isn't deteriorated.
If I did:
async function asyncGetImageDataUrl(source) {
   ...
   image.src = source
   await image.decode()

   ... 
   return dataURI
}

It appears to behave the same way in my testing, but is it? Or does it become blocking
Final question:
Would the result be any different, if I called result = await asyncGetImage(src)?
Perhaps in an instance where I would want it to be blocking.
Added Context:
My usage might look like:
source = getImageSource(..)
if (source == foo) {
   doThis()
}
getImageURL(source, (result) => {
   if (result.length < max) {
      store(result)
   }
   else {
      moreImageProcessing(result, (processedResult) => {
         ...
      }
   }
}

And you can see how the nesting occurs with the initial pattern, and becomes messy.

but is it yes, neither technique blocks

@James If that's the case then that's great news. Thank you

If it helps to picture it (since you understand callbacks) - async await and promise are just fancy wrappers around callbacks.  For example you could promisify your original function using the techniques here and it might be easier to code and maintain, but still does fundamentally the same thing.

Ah that does make a lot of sense looking at it like that.
Looking at the link, yes, that will be a very good solution.
You have my thanks!
